# Autostart pure-ftpd by running its Perl configuration file at the command line

Tags: linux, perl, startup, sysvinit, pure-ftpd

I have manually built the `pure-ftpd` on my Raspberry Pi and it runs perfectly fine when I invoke

`/etc/pure-config.pl /etc/pure-ftpd.conf`

from the command line. I'd like to run that simple command `/etc/pure-config.pl /etc/pure-ftpd.conf` in `init.d` like as if I'm running them at the command line.

The official or the custom `init.d` startup scripts are no good for me because they try to run pure-ftpd directly i.e. without the `/etc/pure-ftpd.conf` file. I need to run it with the `/etc/pure-ftpd.conf` How to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Romario,
It depends on whether your linux distribution uses systemd (most modern ones) or not (the ones that remained sane).

Before `systemd`:

Add your local commands to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` and make this link  `ln -s /etc/rc.d/rc.local /etc/rc5.d/S99local` (assuming you will boot in `runlevel` 5)

after `systemd`:

you should also add your commands to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, but don't forget to `chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local`.

update:

On Raspberry Pi the folder is `rcS.d`. You can change the order the script will be called following [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37456/boot-script-is-not-called-on-boot)

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. On my Raspbian, there's no `/etc/rc.d` folder. There are `rc0.d` . . .  `rc6.d` folders and one `rcS.d` folder and the `rc.local` file but no  `/etc/rc.d` folder. In that case, should I make that folder (in order to ad my local commands into `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`) ?